# Kubernetes Metric Server not able to Collect Metric

Tags: kubernetes

I am having test environment cluster with 1 master and two worker node, all the basic pods are up and running.

```
root@master:~/pre-release# kubectl get pods -n kube-system
NAME                              READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
coredns-74ff55c5b-jn4pl           1/1     Running   0          23h
coredns-74ff55c5b-lz5pq           1/1     Running   0          23h
etcd-master                       1/1     Running   0          23h
kube-apiserver-master             1/1     Running   0          23h
kube-controller-manager-master    1/1     Running   0          23h
kube-flannel-ds-c7czv             1/1     Running   0          150m
kube-flannel-ds-kz74g             1/1     Running   0          150m
kube-flannel-ds-pb4f2             1/1     Running   0          150m
kube-proxy-dbmjn                  1/1     Running   0          23h
kube-proxy-kfrdd                  1/1     Running   0          23h
kube-proxy-wj4rk                  1/1     Running   0          23h
kube-scheduler-master             1/1     Running   0          23h
metrics-server-67fb68f54c-4hnt7   1/1     Running   0          9m
```

Next when i am checking pod logs for metric server i don't see any error message as well

```
root@master:~/pre-release# kubectl -n kube-system logs -f metrics-server-67fb68f54c-4hnt7
I0330 09:53:15.286101       1 serving.go:325] Generated self-signed cert (/tmp/apiserver.crt, /tmp/apiserver.key)
I0330 09:53:15.767767       1 requestheader_controller.go:169] Starting RequestHeaderAuthRequestController
I0330 09:53:15.767790       1 shared_informer.go:240] Waiting for caches to sync for RequestHeaderAuthRequestController
I0330 09:53:15.767815       1 secure_serving.go:197] Serving securely on [::]:4443
I0330 09:53:15.767823       1 configmap_cafile_content.go:202] Starting client-ca::kube-system::extension-apiserver-authentication::requestheader-client-ca-file
I0330 09:53:15.767835       1 shared_informer.go:240] Waiting for caches to sync for client-ca::kube-system::extension-apiserver-authentication::requestheader-client-ca-file
I0330 09:53:15.767857       1 configmap_cafile_content.go:202] Starting client-ca::kube-system::extension-apiserver-authentication::client-ca-file
I0330 09:53:15.767865       1 shared_informer.go:240] Waiting for caches to sync for client-ca::kube-system::extension-apiserver-authentication::client-ca-file
I0330 09:53:15.767878       1 dynamic_serving_content.go:130] Starting serving-cert::/tmp/apiserver.crt::/tmp/apiserver.key
I0330 09:53:15.767897       1 tlsconfig.go:240] Starting DynamicServingCertificateController
I0330 09:53:15.867954       1 shared_informer.go:247] Caches are synced for RequestHeaderAuthRequestController
I0330 09:53:15.868014       1 shared_informer.go:247] Caches are synced for client-ca::kube-system::extension-apiserver-authentication::requestheader-client-ca-file
I0330 09:53:15.868088       1 shared_informer.go:247] Caches are synced for client-ca::kube-system::extension-apiserver-authentication::client-ca-file
```

Then i verified metric services

```
root@master:~/pre-release# kubectl describe apiservice v1beta1.metrics.k8s.io
Name:         v1beta1.metrics.k8s.io
Namespace:
Labels:       k8s-app=metrics-server
Annotations:  <none>
API Version:  apiregistration.k8s.io/v1
Kind:         APIService
Metadata:
  Creation Timestamp:  2021-03-30T09:53:13Z
  Resource Version:    126838
  UID:                 6da11b3f-87d5-4de4-92a0-463219b23301
Spec:
  Group:                     metrics.k8s.io
  Group Priority Minimum:    100
  Insecure Skip TLS Verify:  true
  Service:
    Name:            metrics-server
    Namespace:       kube-system
    Port:            443
  Version:           v1beta1
  Version Priority:  100
Status:
  Conditions:
    Last Transition Time:  2021-03-30T09:53:13Z
    Message:               failing or missing response from https://10.108.112.196:443/apis/metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1: Get "https://10.108.112.196:443/apis/metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
    Reason:                FailedDiscoveryCheck
    Status:                False
    Type:                  Available
Events:                    <none>
```

finally status of type false and ending with above error.

Here the deployment spec file

```
 spec:
      containers:
      - args:
        - /metrics-server
        - --cert-dir=/tmp
        - --secure-port=4443
        - --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP
        - --kubelet-use-node-status-port
        - --kubelet-insecure-tls
```

kubectl top nodes

```
root@master:~# kubectl top nodes
Error from server (ServiceUnavailable): the server is currently unable to handle the request (get nodes.metrics.k8s.io)
```

Now able to find thee solution still from yesterday, could you pleaes help me on this

Comment: What version of Kubernetes do you have ?
Do you have Kubernetes on bare-metal or Managed Kubernetes Service ? 
How did you install the `metrics-server` ? Are you able to run `kubectl top nodes` command ?

Comment: Server version v1.20.5 and client version also same

Comment: Thank you for your response.
How did you install the `metrics-server` ?

Comment: Hi Buddy, i followed git hub url to download the latest version and updated few part about insecure tls, But still i have doubt do we need any self signed certificate certificate for metric server?

Comment: Note all the required ports are opens where my vm are created as well, i am not sure how i am going to resolve this issue could u please help me

Comment: I've tried to reproduce your issue but it seems to work as expected for me.
Is it possible for you to add `hostNetwork:true` under `spec.template.spec` to your `metrics-server` Deployment ?

Comment: Great sir its working now

Comment: Great :) I created the answer for better visibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, adding `hostNetwork:true` under `spec.template.spec` to the `metrics-server` Deployment may help.

```
...
 spec:
      hostNetwork: true
      containers:
      - args:
        - /metrics-server
        - --cert-dir=/tmp
        - --secure-port=4443
        - --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP
        - --kubelet-use-node-status-port
        - --kubelet-insecure-tls
...
```

As we can find in the [Kubernetes Host namespaces documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/pod-security-policy/#host-namespaces):

> HostNetwork - Controls whether the pod may use the node network namespace. Doing so gives the pod access to the loopback device, services listening on localhost, and could be used to snoop on network activity of other pods on the same node.

Comment: Thanks lot your support one week issue you resolved today